# Django url with IP address

Tags: python, django

I want to make this URL pattern works : http://myapp.com/api/ipaddress/username where IP address is an IPv4 and username is the account of a django user.

What is the good regex format to do this at url.py ?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view_api, name='api'),
    url(r'^(?P<ip>[0-9.])/(?P<username>\w+)/$', view_ip_check_user, name='ip_check_user'),
]
```

Comment: You are missing a repeat character for the the IP address part of the regex.

Comment: Try out regexr for when you're building regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know :

I tried this and it works :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', view_api, name='api'),
    url(r'^(?P<ip>(?:(?:0|1[\d]{0,2}|2(?:[0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|[3-9]\d?)\.){3}(?:0|1[\d]{0,2}|2(?:[0-4]\d?|5[0-5]?|[6-9])?|[3-9]\d?))/(?P<pseudo>\w+)/$', view_ip_check_user, name='ip_check_user'),
]
```

This regex only accept valid IPv4 address. So for example wrong address like 172.16.1.256 is not deserved by Django.

So it's perfect.